# How to explain this question and answer on position and velocity vectors from MIT 18.02sc?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is from MIT OCW's multi-variable calculus course 18.02sc on position vectors and velocity vectors.

The question and answer is given below. I don't really understand the answer fully however. I get that the equation of a sphere has the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$, but I don't get how they show the dot product of the two vectors is 0.

**Question:**
[image]
**Answer:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the position vector is given by $\mathbf r(t) = \langle x(t), y(t), z(t) \rangle$ with velocity vector $\mathbf v(t) = \mathbf r'(t) = \langle x'(t), y'(t), z'(t) \rangle.$ Considering that the point $P$ whose position is given by $\mathbf r(t)$ lies on the surface of the sphere centered at the origin, we must have that $x^2(t) + y^2(t) + z^2(t) = a^2,$ where $a$ is the radius of the sphere. (Recall that the surface of the sphere of radius $a$ centered at the origin consists of the points $(x, y, z)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2.$) By taking the derivative with respect to $t,$ we have that $$2x(t) x'(t) + 2y(t) y'(t) + 2z(t) z'(t) = 0$$ by the Chain Rule. But this says exactly that $$\mathbf v(t) \cdot \mathbf r(t) = \langle x'(t), y'(t), z'(t) \rangle \cdot \langle x(t), y(t), z(t) \rangle = xx' + yy' + zz' = 0$$ for all $t,$ from which it follows that $\mathbf r(t)$ and $\mathbf v(t) = \mathbf r'(t)$ are perpendicular.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. Does the 2 need to be considered here?

Comment: Not at all. It is a factor of each term on the left-hand side, so we can simply divide both sides by it to eliminate it.